# How to center div element that overlay a slider

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a revolution slider as background, and I want to overlay with a static div centered in the middle of the slider.

The problem is that I am not able to center this div. Where do I wrong?
Here is the page https://www.visitmontaione.com/wcomm/it/

This is the HTML code used:

```
    <div id="containersliderhome">
  [rev_slider alias="slider-1"][/rev_slider]
  <div id="barrabookingforhome">Centered DIV
  </div>
```

and css

```
#barrabookingforhome{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin: 10px;
background: red;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
z-index:999;
}

#containersliderhome{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your link seems to redirect to /en version at the moment and can't replicate the situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you this CSS to centre div on https://www.visitmontaione.com/wcomm/it/. You have to only add `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);` to your CSS `#barrabookingforhome`.

```css
#barrabookingforhome {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Yes, it center, but I don't understand why the div element with 100% do not expand for all the width of the page.